# Ignore prefix titles like "Mr." when using Regex Split()

Tags: c#, regex, split

Is there a pattern for use with Regular Expressions that is able to ignore prefix titles like "Mr." or "Ms." from splitting at the period?

For example, lets say our string was: "Mr. X did so and so. Blah blah blah." 
I want to be able to split at the end of a sentence period but not at a title for a person.

Comment: Just in case you didn't realise: there are other scenarios where periods are not used to terminate a sentence too. Two examples off of the top of my head are currencies ($ 1.50) and ellipses (...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this should work for you

```
string input = "Mr. and MRS. X did so and so... blah blah blah.";
var tokens = Regex.Split( input, @"(?<!\bMr|\bMs|\bMrs)[.]{1,3}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
```

This would produce ["Mr and MRS. X did so and so", " blah blah blah"] as tokens. The important part is the negative lookbehind portion of the pattern.

```
(?<!\bMr|\bMs|\bMrs)
```

So the regex will only match a period **NOT** preceded by one of those titles.

Comment: Good answer, though not without room for improvement: this is case sensitive (it wouldn't work for "MR. X DID SO AND SO. BLAH BLAH BLAH."), but making it work for entirely uppercase texts too would introduce problems because ordinary words at the end of a sentence may happen to end in `Ms`. Suggestion: use `\b`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this splitting. Negative lookbehind doesn't support variable length in it. So either you have to make it a fixed length, or need to use multiple one.

Using multiple lookbehind. It means the `dot` is not exactly after `Mr`, `Ms` or `Mrs`

```
var tokens = Regex.Split(input, "(?<!Mr|Ms)(?<!Mrs)[.]");
```

Or using fixed length, but I do not recommend it as it will not work in some cases(for example `Mr.` at the beginning of the line or for the text `xMr.`). I am just adding this for reference as I believe you are learning regex!

```
var tokens = Regex.Split(input, "(?<!.Mr|.Ms|Mrs)[.]");
```